# How To Enable Unbound DNSSEC DNS Resolver On Mac OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite

Tags: macos, dns, resolver, dnssec

I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite. Very recently upgraded from Snow Leopard (10.6.8) to Yosemite.

### Step A

On my MacBook, I login into an Admin type privileged account. I installed the latest free XCode from the Apple App Store. With XCode, I also installed Command Line Tools, etc.

### Step B

I installed Homebrew from https://brew.sh/. This is the command-line code I ran in Terminal, from the Homebrew website:

```sh
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

The script above checks for the presence of various necessary software & settings, and it showed (info & status inside Terminal window, on) what other commands or tools are needed to be obtained or executed. I followed those.

### Step C

When Homebrew & related installation steps were done, I then installed `openssl` & `unbound` with the `brew` tool, via command-lines in Terminal:

```sh
brew help
brew update
brew install unbound openssl
sudo cp -fv /usr/local/opt/unbound/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.unbound.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.unbound.plist
brew upgrade --all
```

### Step D

I restarted my MacBook once, and then tried the `dig` commands below.  They **did not show the `ad` flags** in DNS query result, which indicates that DNSSEC authenticated DNS resolving is still not working and disabled!

```
dig @127.0.0.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.dnssec-validator.cz. +dnssec
dig @127.0.0.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.isc.org. +dnssec
dig @192.168.10.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.dnssec-validator.cz. +dnssec
dig @192.168.10.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.isc.org. +dnssec
```

The 192.168.10.1 is my (internet router) gateway for my primary network interface/adapter which is connected to the internet.  My net adapter is currently using 192.168.10.50, a dynamic (not fixed) DHCP based IP address.

Unfortunately, the developers at https://unbound.net/ do not provide a standalone Unbound `.pkg` or `.dmg` installer file for Mac OS X.  They do not actively develop the DNSSEC-Trigger app, either.  In Snow Leopard, I was only using the Unbound portion of the DNSSEC-Trigger bundle.  I was able to disable the DNSSEC-Trigger portion, and kept the Unbound portion running, after following tips shown in their mailing-list archive. In that way, I did not need to install any XCode command-line tools or Homebrew.

What should I do now so that all apps on my MacBook can use the Unbound DNSSEC resolver for all apps/clients? I want Unbound's resolver to be listening on 127.0.0.1 port 53 for DNSSEC & DNS queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These set of steps worked on Mac OS X Yosemite MacBook.

I'm self-answering with general elaboration to make it more clear for newbies, if you are not newbie then please skip whatever is unnecessary for you.

If you don't want to install very large installation of XCode, then see Step E below, first. Otherwise, start with the steps in the original question.

### Step E

#### E1

My own account in Mac OS is `Erik-user`. It is a standard user account, which I generally use for general purposes.
But the `Erik` account is for administrative purposes. It is an "Admin" type, **privileged** user account.  I'm using the `Erik` account.

#### E2

To enable showing hidden files inside Finder file browser, use the commands below in Terminal:

```bash
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

and then log out & log back into your MacOS user account, or restart MacOS. Now "Finder" should show you all files & folders, in `[ | | ]` column mode.

If you have already installed "XCode" and homebrew, then skip the rest of Step E and continue from Step F.

#### E3

If you want to avoid installing the multi-gigabyte XCode,

- Run this command inside Terminal: `xcode-select --install` and a new window will appear. In it, select only "Command Line Tools" (CLT) option/portion, even though it suggests that you install full XCode.
- Then verify CLT installation: so in Terminal, run: `xcode-select -p`

  - If it displays: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` then CLT installation succeeded.

Mac OS X Yosemite allows you to install only the CLT portion. Some previous Mac OS X versions did not allow CLT without XCode.

Also check if the `gcc` tool is now present or not: in Terminal, run: `gcc --version`

#### E4

Install Homebrew. In Terminal run:

```bash
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Please see https://brew.sh/ website for the actual & current `ruby` command.
Then in Terminal, run these commands:

```bash
brew help
brew update
brew install unbound openssl
```

#### E5

```bash
sudo cp -fv /usr/local/opt/unbound/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.unbound.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.unbound.plist
```

If you followed Steps E3 to E5, then skip Step F, and start to follow from Step G.

### Step F

The `homebrew.mxcl.unbound.plist` file (which starts the Unbound DNS server) specifically needs to have *proper ownership,* so that Mac OS X's system itself can start it during boot or restart. Execute this command in Terminal:

```bash
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.unbound.plist
```

Note: After upgrading Homebrew apps, we may need to execute this command again, if Unbound fails to start after a reboot.

### Step G

[Download Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/) from SourceForge. Install it. Start Lingon.

### Step H

Inside Lingon, locate `homebrew.mxcl.unbound` under "USER DAEMONS."
In the "What" textbox, it is supposed to show like below:
`/usr/local/opt/unbound/sbin/unbound -d -c /usr/local/etc/unbound/unbound.conf`
Select & copy that last portion `/usr/local/etc/unbound/unbound.conf`.

### Step I

Open `/usr/local/etc/unbound/unbound.conf` with your favorite text editor.

### Step J: `unbound.conf` file content

The **unbound.conf** file has many pages of configuration info & config-command examples.
See below codes, **add only these below config-command code lines** at bottom of unbound.conf file or in appropriate section.

```yaml
server:
    verbosity: 1
    num-threads: 2
    interface: 127.0.0.1
    interface: ::1
    port: 53
    do-ip4: yes
    do-ip6: yes
    do-udp: yes
    do-tcp: yes
    do-daemonize: yes
    #module-config: "[dns64] [validator] iterator"
    module-config: "validator iterator"
    auto-trust-anchor-file: "/usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key"
    #dlv-anchor-file: "/usr/local/etc/unbound/dlv.isc.org.key"
```

Note: I skipped showing instruction for DLV DNSSEC, so added the (shown-above) `#` symbol in front of the `dlv-anchor-file` line, to disable it.  And one of the `module-config` lines is also disabled, as I don't want DNS64 related resolution, for now.

### Step K: `unbound.conf` file permissions

Set file **ownership**:

```bash
sudo chown root /usr/local/etc/unbound/unbound.conf
```

Set file **permissions** for different ownerships:

```bash
sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/etc/unbound/unbound.conf
```

#### A short discourse on file [permission](http://ss64.com/osx/chmod.html) and [ownership](http://ss64.com/osx/chown.html)

Permission level 4 = **r**ead, 2 = **w**rite, 1 = e**x**ecute. 3-digit number is for 3-types of ownership: Owner-Group-Other.
By using Finder's GUI interface, you can also set permissions & ownerships of a file, instead of using command-lines in Terminal: select a file in Finder, press Cmd+i buttons together, go below in "Sharing & Permissions" section, the "Name" column shows list of users/groups who owns ownership, the "Privilege" column shows file's read/write permissions level for different ownership. Change into recommended choices & preference level shown here.
Except for very reliable person, and only-this computer's core (operating-system) system components, no one else (and no other entity) should have the ability to (edit & change or) write, into some of the sensitive files & folders, that is why we need to set "Permissions-level" on files & folders. The "6" in "644" (which is used in "chmod" command-line) is indicating current-user's (aka "Me") permissions-level, and current user ("Me") has ("6" can be broken down into 4+2) read+write level permissions. The middle "4" in "644" is permission for user-type or user-group, and that group/type of users have ("4") read level permissions. Then right-most side "4" in "644" is permission for Everyone/Other/World users and they have ("4") read level permissions.

### Step L: Verify `unbound.conf`

Check if `unbound.conf` file **configuration** has any error, by using this command, in Terminal:

```bash
sudo /usr/local/opt/unbound/sbin/unbound-checkconf  "/usr/local/etc/unbound/unbound.conf"
```

### Step M: Obtaining a `root.key` anchor

Follow instruction shown in OPTION-1, if you dont have a "root.key" file for "unbound" DNS server/Resolver, and you want to manually create an "initial" root.key file by yourself with very thorough checking, and if you want unbound DNS Server daemon to update that initial root.key, with a working full root.key code & timestamps.

Follow instruction shown in OPTION-2, if you dont have a (initial or working) "root.key" file, and if you want the "unbound-anchor" tool to QUICKLY create it for you.

Follow instruction shown in OPTION-3, if you dont have a (initial or working) "root.key" file, but you have securely obtained "icannbundle.pem" file, from IANA/ICANN authority website, and you want "unbound-anchor" tool to create it (full working root.key) very securely.

Follow instruction shown in OPTION-4, if you don't have a (initial or working) "root.key" file, but you have access to another "safe" or "secured" computer, where you can securely obtain files from authority websites, or you can copy a working "root.key" file from it, for your MacOSX computer.

#### M option 1: Manually creating a new `root.key`

A regular user may want to **view** or obtain (or manually create) correct "**initial**" "root.key" (aka, initial **root-trust-anchor**) via HTTPS (encrypted & non-eavesdropped & secured) connection from **IANA** authority website: [`root-anchors.xml`](https://data.iana.org/root-anchors/root-anchors.xml), or obtain initial anchor from **ICANN** authority website, and then regular user MUST **compare+verify** xml file's content code, with local initial root.key file.
Click on the above xml URL-link, and then check presence of a LOCK-icon shown in web-browser's url-bar (which is an indicative that a HTTPS encrypted connection is being used), and also check color of "DNSSEC-Validator" (and "TLSA-Validator") status icon, (it must display a picture of green-colored KEY-icon).
Either download the xml file or copy-paste the content shown in xml file, into the "root-anchors.xml" file, and place/move it in same folder where "unbound.conf" file is located.
And now copy the file "root-anchors.xml" file in same folder, and rename the "root-anchors Copy.xml" file into "root.key".
And edit this "root.key" file (by using nano or Bluefish text-editor app). And change/re-arrange existing XML syntax/format, into the format shown in below "**DS**" code line. Make sure all numbers & hash codes in "root.key" are exactly same number & hash, shown on that IANA authority webpage "root-anchors.xml" file.  Format/Syntax will be different in those two files, but code & hash numbers must be same.
Currently (June, 2015), the 2010-2011 initial trust anchor (initial **root.key**) for the root zone, looks like below.

```
. IN DS 19036 8 2 49AAC11D7B6F6446702E54A1607371607A1A41855200FD2CE1CDDE32F24E8FB5
```

And then set file ownership: `sudo chown root /usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key`
and set permissions: `sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key`

Codes shown in above "**DS**" code-line, (which must also be present in INITIAL "root.key" file), is known as "**Initial Anchor**".  Unbound server daemon or "unbound-anchor" tool can update initial file with a working full root.key, with appropriate codes & timestamps.

#### M option 2: Creating a new `root.key` with `unbound-anchor` using local certificates

Another QUICK (short) way (and not very secure/trustworthy way) to obtain+create the "root.key" file, is to, use the unbound tool "**unbound-anchor**", via a command in Terminal:
`sudo /usr/local/opt/unbound/sbin/unbound-anchor -a "/usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key"`
With above command, unbound-anchor tool obtains appropriate codes or files from authority websites (if a newer version is found) by using internal certificates, and then creates the "root.key" file, containing working codes & timestamps.
And then set file ownership on it: `sudo chown root /usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key`
and set permissions: `sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key`

#### M option 3: Creating a new `root.key` with `unbound-anchor` using ICANN certificates

`unbound-anchor` can also obtain and create a working `root.key` even **more securely,** if an `icannbundle.pem` file is supplied/used.
So 1st obtain `icannbundle.pem file` securely from [the IANA authority website](https://www.iana.org/dnssec/files) (and make sure your web browser's address bar is showing LOCK-icon & green-colored dnssec KEY-icon), and download the `pem` file into this directory: `/usr/local/etc/unbound`
And then set file ownership: `sudo chown root /usr/local/etc/unbound/icannbundle.pem`
and set permissions: `sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/etc/unbound/icannbundle.pem`
Then obtain+create a working root.key very securely, by using this command in Terminal:
`sudo /usr/local/opt/unbound/sbin/unbound-anchor -a "/usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key" -c "/usr/local/etc/unbound/icannbundle.pem"`
With above command, unbound-anchor tool obtains appropriate codes or files from authority websites (if a newer version is found) by using internal certificates, and then checks authenticity of received code by using the icannbundle.pem cryptographic key file, and then creates the "root.key" file, containing working codes & timestamps.
And now we can set file ownership on root.key: `sudo chown root /usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key`
and set permissions: `sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/etc/unbound/root.key`
For more detail info, goto: http**s**://**unbound.net**/documentation/howto_anchor.html and also check http**s**://**unbound.net**/documentation/unbound-anchor.html

#### M option 4: Obtaining a `root.key` from another computer where it has been created

Note: User/visitor suppose to use already pre-setup safe computer & web-browser software to "securely" **obtain/download** those files (root-anchors.xml, or, icannbundle.pem, etc) from ICANN or IANA authority website.  Web-browser software, MUST have "DNSSEC-Validator" (and "TLSA-Validator") (also known as DNSSEC/TLSA-Validator) extension/addon (from this https://www.dnssec-validator.cz/ website), and that computer must also have a local full DNSSEC supported DNS Server or resolver.
And then in such web-browser, a user/visitor can see correct DNSSEC & DANE/TLSA status icon (green-colored KEY-icon), for each visiting websites (which are appropriately DNSSEC-Signed).
If an "unbound" DNS Server/Resolver is used in that "SAFE" & "SECURED" computer, then you can **copy** that "root.key" file from it, into your MacOSX computer, when you want to avoid going into authority websites & want to avoid checking very thoroughly, and when you want to quickly configure a 2nd/other computer.
Also load these firefox extensions/addons, and then enable "add-on bar" (similar to statusbar) at bottomside of firefox, for viewing more info on web server location & reverse DNS address, and more info on server's TLS/SSL certificate:
CipherFox, Cert Viewer Plus, Calomel SSL Validation, HTTPS-Everywhere, WorldIP, Classic Theme Restorer, etc.

### Step N

In your Mac OS X computer, goto "**System Preferences**" > **Network** >  choose each "WiFi" and each "Ethernet" Network Interface Card/Adapter, which is/are connected with internet in your Apple MacBook computer > goto/click "Advanced" > goto "DNS" tab >  (write-down which adapter has which set of DNS Servers in a paper, and then, one by one adapter) remove the DNS-servers which are listed there, and make sure, that, only **one DNS server** is listed/specified: **127.0.0.1**

Above steps will create+add "nameserver 127.0.0.1" code, inside /etc/resolv.conf file.

### Step O

If you are using 10.10.3 or earlier, then keep mDNS (mDNSResponder)  completely disabled. By using "Lingon" app, look for mDNS ("com.apple.**mDNSResponder**"), check all 4 sections inside Lingon, specially under SYSTEM DAEMONS, click on the text "Show" next to each section, to view full list.
mDNS is re-included back in 10.10.4 (by Apple updates), so if you are using 10.10.4 then disable it temporarily just for these steps-o.
If it is active or found in 10.10.3 or earlier, then uncheck/unselect the "Enabled" option in Lingon to disable it, enter administrative user pass, save/ok.
When mDNS is active, it starts to resolve DNS and it also does bunch of other activity automatically, (like, discovering & configuring UPnP IGD & NAT-PMP, etc) without taking computer-owner's permission or without showing any info (or table of info) to computer's owner, what exactly its doing. So mDNS does not show computer's owner, any information on which apps are allowed by it, to do what, and what port/traffic activities are going on on or through your computer, etc, none are displayed to computer's owner, so mDNS is not an app with some good technologies for people & their computer's safety & security & privacy in mind.  And mDNS by itself does not support full DNSSEC either, unless at-least one local/remote BIND or Unbound full dnssec dns server is used.

### Step P

If you are using 10.10.3 or earlier, then disable it temporarily just for these steps-p. By using Lingon, find "com.apple.networking.**discoveryd**" under SYSTEM DAEMONS.  Uncheck/unselect the "Enabled" option in Lingon to disable it temporarily, enter administrative user pass, save/ok.  We are disabling it, so that it can completely forget the previous/old DNS Servers, which were obtained from network adapter's DNS setting, (it will forget after one restart from this stage).
Discoveryd is removed from 10.10.4 (by Apple updates), so if you are using 10.10.4 then disable it completely, if still exists.

### Step Q

By using Lingon, find "com.apple.**dnsextd**" under SYSTEM DAEMONS.  Uncheck/unselect the "Enabled" option in Lingon to disable/de-activate it, enter administrative user pass, save/ok.

### Step R

In Terminal, run

```bash
dig @127.0.0.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.isc.org. +dnssec
```

And open "App Store" and see if it can pull homepage contents/items.

Reboot/restart MacOSX once.

### Step S

#### S1

If you are using 10.10.3 or earlier, then enable "discoveryd" back, now, at this stage of this instruction steps-s. Again use Lingon, find the "com.apple.networking.**discoveryd**". Select/checkmark the "Enabled" option, enter administrative user pass, save/ok.
Discoveryd is removed from 10.10.4 (by Apple updates), so if you are using 10.10.4, then still keep "discoveryd" disabled, if still exists.

#### S2

If you are using 10.10.4 or later, then enable "mDNS" back, now, at this stage. Again use Lingon, find the "com.apple.**mDNSResponder**" under SYSTEM DAEMONS. Select/checkmark the "Enabled" option, enter administrative user pass, save/ok.

#### S3

Many apps use system/default DNS resolving when allowed & serviced by the (above shown) "discoveryd" daemon (aka, Discovery Daemon), in 10.10.3 & earlier Mac OS X, or DNS resolving service is allowed to be accessed by mDNS daemon in 10.10.4 or later Mac OS X.  Either of this daemon should be now able to learn & allow other apps to use the new DNSSEC DNS Server service running at 127.0.0.1 port-53, which is specified in Network adapter's DNS settings, (after one restart from this stage).

### Step T

In Terminal, run

```bash
dig @127.0.0.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.isc.org. +dnssec
```

And open "App Store" and see if it can pull homepage contents/items.

Reboot/restart one more time again.

### Step U

Now in Terminal, run below "dig" commands, and **check** if query results are showing "**ad**" in flag, and status is showing "NOERROR".  If those indicators are present, then full dnssec dns resolving is working from a local dnssec resolver, running-at & listening-on 127.0.0.1 port 53/DNS. :)

```bash
dig @127.0.0.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.dnssec-validator.cz. +dnssec
dig @127.0.0.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.isc.org. +dnssec
dig @127.0.0.1 in TLSA _443._tcp.www.statdns.net. +dnssec
ping yahoo.com
nslookup yahoo.com
```

If `nslookup` or `ping` worked, then it indicates that the default DNS Server is working.
Remove the "@127.0.0.1" portion from above "dig" commands, and **check** if results are same (that is, "ad" flag is still shown, and if dig results are still showing it has by-default used the 127.0.0.1 as DNS server),  then it is indicating, by default local 127.0.0.1 DNS Server is being used as system-wide DNS Server/Resolver (for allmost all apps/tools), and dnssec based resolving is also working.

### Step V

Some tools & apps do not completely use other DNS servers, they contain their own internal full DNSSEC/DNS resolving library & related codes or contains partial library-codes, so checking DNS with only such tools are not enough.
You must check it via other apps (which you daily use or) which are known to use system network adapter's DNS servers.

So you must fireup Firefox and Apple App Store, and **check** if you can see & visit all websites normally, as those apps will be using the "default" (aka, "system") DNS resolver/server, which is now set-to 127.0.0.1 by us, what we have specified inside network adapter configuration.

### Step W

Firewall based restrictions & assistance:
By using **application-aware firewall** + network port/packet control firewall, if we set firewall-rules shown below, then entire system can be FORCED TO USE, only ONE full dnssec DNS Server/Resolver 127.0.0.1 & nothing else:
system-wide/global firewall rule #1: only "unbound" app can connect with any other DNS-Server's port 53/DNS using TCP or UDP connection.
system-wide/global firewall rule #2: any app/software which is NOT-"unbound", can only use one "unbound" DNS-Server running-at & listening-on 127.0.0.1 port 53/DNS using TCP or UDP connection. (So all other port 53 traffics are dropped for non-unbound app/software).

### Steps X and Y

(Deleted)

### Step Z: Notes, Disclaimers, and References

I have followed (and borrowed instructions, and discussion comments from) various other websites, (and copy-pasted instructions & comments here with slight modifications done by me).  Some references i showed, under the paragraph, when related content was first mentioned, in this article/answer page.  So, for even more detail understanding, please search in ddg/yahoo/bing/google engines with terms/words taken from here.
Different computer may & very likely to have different versions and configurations and components. So you MUST research & use your own best educated knowledge & judgement, before using any of these shown instructions on your own computer at your own risk.